# Prove that an injective immersion of closed manifolds is an embedding

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

> **Definition:** An embedding of manifolds is a differentiable map $f:N^n\hookrightarrow M^m$ which has an injective pushforward. An immersion of manifolds $f:N^n\looparrowright M^m$ is a differentiable map which is locally an embedding. That is, for every $x\in N$, there is an open $V\subset N$ such that $x\in V$ and $f|_V: V \hookrightarrow M$ is an embedding.

I am attempting to prove the following lemma; my attempt is below.

> **Lemma:** Any injective immersion of closed manifolds $f:N\looparrowright M$ is an embedding.
>
> > *Proof:* Take a cover of $N$ by open sets $\{U_i\subset N\}_{i\in I}$ such that $f|_{U_i}:U_i\hookrightarrow M$ is an embedding. Take a finite subcover $\{U_i'\}_{i=1}^k$ and let $\{\varphi_i:N\to [0,1]\}_{i=1}^k$ be a partition of unity subordinate to $\{U_i'\}$. Then for any $x\in X$
> > \begin{equation}
> > D_xf= \sum_{i=1}^k \varphi_i(\delta_i(x)) \delta_i(x_i)
> > \end{equation}
> > Where $\delta_i(x)=D_x f|_{U_i'}$ if $x\in U_i'$ and $0$ otherwise. This is injective because each $D_xf|_{U_i'}$ is injective.

I know this is incorrect but I'm wondering if it could be fixed (I'd prefer an answer using partitions of unity - if that is the right thing to use here).

Comment: Your definitions are wrong. An immersion is a differentiable map whose pushforward is injective at each point, and an embedding is an immersion that is also a homeomorphism onto its image (in the subspace topology). It's also true that a differentiable map is an immersion if and only if it's locally an embedding, but that's not the definition.

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $f: X\to Y$ is a continuous injective map with compact domain and Hausdorff  range. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism to its image.